# What do I need to add with "using" to get my code to run?

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

I am looking at some code for using a hub with signalr, C#, and asp.net.  There are red squigglies under:

```
public override Task OnConnected()

public override System.Threading.Tasks.Task OnDisconnected()

return base.OnDisconnected();
```

What do I need to include as using to get the code to run?

These have been added already :

```
using System.Linq;  
using System.Web;  
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
```

There are red squigglies under the words :

```
Task OnConnected() and 
OnDisconnected().
```

Comment: hit "ctrl" + "." over those methods

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to overload the [`OnConnected`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/jj890472(v%3Dvs.118)) and [`OnDisconnected`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/jj890492(v=vs.118)) methods of the Hub, you will need to fill in the actual method.

```
public override Task OnConnected()
{
   // your code here
   return base.OnConnected();
}

public override Task OnDisconnected()
{
   // your code here
   return base.OnDisconnected();
}
```

However, it's debatable whether you actually want to do this at all. It's more than likely you don't need this code and it can be completely omitted.

Comment: I am indeed trying to get this code working this way, I am just not including the correct usings.

Answer (score 0):

If those are all of your using statements then you are probably also missing `System.Threading.Tasks`. Although with so little information it could be anything. Typically Visual Studio will indicate to you what you need to do to make the red squiggles go away. If not then it may be a missing or broken Nuget package or an inconsistency in framework versions.

Good luck my dude.

Comment: Thanks, that got rid of one of them, anyone know the other one?

Comment: Are you actually inheriting from some class? I.E. - public class YourClass : SomeOtherClass{}

Comment: I usually use C++, but chathub is inheriting from hub class.

Comment: OnDisconnected() is the last missing using.

Comment: there is an override of bool stopcalled in the parenthesis but the other OnDiconnect works with only a true or false in the parenthesis?!!??

Comment: Yeah. So if you look at the GitHub for SignalR it doesn't seem that there is an actual parameterless version of `OnDisconnect` as you are trying to call it. It looks like the only available version of `OnDisconnect(bool)` is the parameterized version which requires a boolean value. If you change `return base.OnDisconnect()` to `return base.OnDisconnect(false)` you should see the error disappear.